# How can I do Many to Multiple Many relationship in Room Android?

Tags: java, android, database, android-room

I want to create a database like below. I followed the documentation but couldn't find any similar examples. Can you help me? There will be days and within these days there will be multiple Daily Meals and Daily Water tables

A day database will be created as soon as the app is started and then whatever day it is in (can change the dates manually) daily water and daily meals will be added into that day

```
            "days":
            [
                {
                    "id": "Integer",
                    "date": "String",
                    "weight": "Float",
                    "height": "Integer",
                    "waist_circumference": "Integer",
                    "neck_circumference": "Integer",
                    "hip_circumference": "Integer",
                    "steps": "Long",
                    "taken_kcal": "Float",
                    "burned_kcal": "Float",
                    "carb": "Float",
                    "protein": "Float",
                    "fat": "Float",
                    "water_ml": "Integer",
                    "water_percent": "Float",
                    "meals":
                    [
                        {
                            "day_id": "Integer",
                            "id": "Integer",
                            "food_meal_time": "String",
                            "food_name": "String",
                            "food_image": "String",
                            "food_kcal": "Float",
                            "food_portion": "String",
                            "food_carb": "Float",
                            "food_protein": "Float",
                            "food_fat": "Float"
                        },
                        {
                            "day_id": "Integer",
                            "id": "Integer",
                            "food_meal_time": "String",
                            "food_name": "String",
                            "food_image": "String",
                            "food_kcal": "Float",
                            "food_portion": "String",
                            "food_carb": "Float",
                            "food_protein": "Float",
                            "food_fat": "Float"
                        }
                    ],
                    "water":
                    [
                        {
                            "day_id": "Integer",
                            "id": "Integer",
                            "water_ml": "Float",
                            "water_percent": "Float",
                            "water_time": "Long"
                        },
                        {
                            "day_id": "Integer",
                            "id": "Integer",
                            "water_ml": "Float",
                            "water_percent": "Float",
                            "water_time": "Long"
                        },
                        {
                            "day_id": "Integer",
                            "id": "Integer",
                            "water_ml": "Float",
                            "water_percent": "Float",
                            "water_time": "Long"
                        }
                    ]
                }
    ]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 core tables (**`@Entity`** annotated classes defined in the entities list of the **`@Database`** annotation), Days, Meals and Water.

**If** (see **However** below) you want a many-many relationship between Days and Meals and also between Days and Water then you would have an associative/mapping/reference (and other terms) table for each many-many relationship. Such a table has two columns one that uniquely associates/references/maps to the Day and the other that uniquely associates/reference/maps to the Meals, for the Days-Meals or in the case of the Days-Water associates/references/maps to the Water. Typically the association/reference/map will be to the id column.

So in your case (**if as per the heading**) you would have two of these tables.

To extract related data (Days with the related Meals and with the related Waters) then you have a POJO that has the Days **`@Embedded`** and an **`@Relation`** to the Meals, defining the associative/reference/mapping table using the **`@Associate`** and the **`@Junction`** annotation, likewise an `@Relation` to the Waters.

**However**, your JSON describes two one-many relationships rather then two many-many relationships. That is the Meals have a reference to the parent Days and likewise the Waters have a reference to the parent Days.

In this case you just need the 3 core tables. For extracting the Days with the related Meals and also with the related Waters. You use the **`@Embedded`** annotation for the Days and **`@Relation`** for both the Meals and the Waters without the *`@Associate`* and *`@Juntion`* as there is no associative/reference/mapping table.

**Working Example**
This working example uses both a

- 1 (Day) to many (Meals and Waters), and
- Many-Many (via mapping tables) allowing the same Meal to be used by many Days and also likewise the same Water to be used by many Days a Day being capable of having many of either.

So the 3 core tables (entities) **Day**, **Water** and **Meal**.

**Day** (note a row is a Day so typically it is the Day table rather than Days table) :-

```
@Entity
public class Day {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long dayId = null;
    String date;
    Float weight;
    /* etc */

    Day(){} /* Room will use this constructor */
    @Ignore /* Tell Room to ignore this constructor, but still usable outside of Room, so makes life easier */
    Day(String date, Float weight) {
        this.dayId = null; /* not needed but effectively what happens */
        this.date = date;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    /* No getters and setters required as members aren't private/protected */
}
```

**Meal**

```
@Entity(
        /* Optional but suggested */
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(
                        entity = Day.class,
                        parentColumns = {"dayId"},
                        childColumns = {"dayId_Meal_Map"}
                        /* Optional but can be useful */
                        , onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
                        , onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
                )
        }
)
class Meal {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long mealId=null;
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    long dayId_Meal_Map;
    String food_meal_time;
    /* etc */

    Meal(){}
    @Ignore
    Meal(long parentDayId, String food_meal_time) {
        this.dayId_Meal_Map = parentDayId;
        this.food_meal_time = food_meal_time;
    }
    @Ignore
    Meal(String food_meal_time) {
        this.food_meal_time = food_meal_time;
    }
}
```

- Note for M2M then you wouldn't have the reference to the parent day, as this is held within the mapping table, as such you wouldn't have the Foreign Key definition either, nor the index on the reference column.
- For a similar reason two @Ignored constructors when one would suffice depending upon wether 1-M or M-M is used.

**Water**

```
@Entity(
        /* Optional but suggested */
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(
                        entity = Day.class,
                        parentColumns = {"dayId"},
                        childColumns = {"dayId_Water_Map"}
                        /* Optional but can be useful */
                        , onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
                        , onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
                )
        }
)
class Water {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long waterId=null;
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    long dayId_Water_Map;
    Float water_ml;
    /* etc */

    Water(){}
    @Ignore
    Water(long parentDayId, Float water_ml) {
        this.dayId_Water_Map = parentDayId;
        this.water_ml = water_ml;
    }
    /* Constructor for m2m i.e. reference to dayId is not needed as in the mapping table */
    @Ignore
    Water(Float water_ml) {
        this.water_ml = water_ml;
    }
}
```

For the **Many-Many** relationship then the 2 mapping tables **DayMealMap** and **DayWaterMap**

**DayMealMap**

```
@Entity(
        primaryKeys = {"dayMealMap_dayId_Reference","dayMealMap_mealId_Reference"},
        /* Optional but suggested */
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(
                        entity = Day.class,
                        parentColumns = {"dayId"},
                        childColumns = {"dayMealMap_dayId_Reference"}
                        /* Optional but helpful */
                        , onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
                        , onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE

                ),
                @ForeignKey(
                        entity = Meal.class,
                        parentColumns = "mealId",
                        childColumns = "dayMealMap_mealId_Reference"
                        , onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
                        , onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
                )
        }
)
class DayMealMap {
    long dayMealMap_dayId_Reference;
    /* Index optional but would likely improve efficiency */
    /* Also ROOM will issue warning if not indexed */
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    long dayMealMap_mealId_Reference;


    DayMealMap(){}
    @Ignore
    DayMealMap(long dayIdMap, long mealIdMap) {
        this.dayMealMap_dayId_Reference = dayIdMap;
        this.dayMealMap_mealId_Reference = mealIdMap;
    }
}
```

**DayWaterMap**

```
@Entity(
        primaryKeys = {"dayWaterMap_dayId_Reference","dayWaterMap_waterId_Reference"},
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(
                        entity = Day.class,
                        parentColumns = "dayId",
                        childColumns = "dayWaterMap_dayId_Reference"
                        , onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
                        , onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
                ),
                @ForeignKey(
                        entity = Water.class,
                        parentColumns = "waterId",
                        childColumns = "dayWaterMap_waterId_Reference"
                        ,onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
                        ,onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
                )
        }
)
class DayWaterMap {
    long dayWaterMap_dayId_Reference;
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    long dayWaterMap_waterId_Reference;

    DayWaterMap(){}
    @Ignore
    DayWaterMap(long dayIdMap, long waterIdMap) {
        this.dayWaterMap_dayId_Reference = dayIdMap;
        this.dayWaterMap_waterId_Reference = waterIdMap;
    }
}
```

For extract of the Days with the Related Meals and Waters via the 1-M relationship then a POJO

```
class DayWithRelatedMealsAlsoWithRelatedWaters {
   @Embedded
   Day day;
   @Relation(
           entity = Meal.class,
           parentColumn = "dayId",
           entityColumn = "dayId_Meal_Map"
   )
   List<Meal> mealList;
   @Relation(
           entity = Water.class,
           parentColumn = "dayId",
           entityColumn = "dayId_Water_Map"
   )
   List<Water> waterList;
}
```

For the Many-Many, to get the same related data it's POJO (via the mapping table (aka the associative tables))

```
class M2MDayWithRelatedMealsAlsoWithRealtedWaters {
   @Embedded
   Day day;
   @Relation(
           entity = Meal.class,
           parentColumn = "dayId",
           entityColumn = "mealId",
           associateBy = @Junction(
                   value = DayMealMap.class,
                   parentColumn = "dayMealMap_dayId_Reference",
                   entityColumn = "dayMealMap_mealId_Reference"
           )
   )
   List<Meal> mealList;
   @Relation(
           entity = Water.class,
           parentColumn = "dayId",
           entityColumn = "waterId",
           associateBy = @Junction(
                   value = DayWaterMap.class,
                   parentColumn = "dayWaterMap_dayId_Reference",
                   entityColumn = "dayWaterMap_waterId_Reference"
           )
   )
   List<Water> waterList;

}
```

An `@Dao` annotated abstract class (could be an interface but I prefer an abstract class as it is more flexible (reasons beyond this question))

**AllDao** (i.e. All of the DAO methods in one, for convenience):-

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract long insert(Day day);
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract long insert(Meal meal);
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract long insert(Water water);

    /* For many-many mapping table inserts */
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract long insert(DayMealMap dayMealMap);
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract long insert(DayWaterMap dayWaterMap);

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM day")
    abstract List<DayWithRelatedMealsAlsoWithRelatedWaters> getListOfDaysWithRelatedMealsAndRelatedWaters();

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM day")
    abstract List<M2MDayWithRelatedMealsAlsoWithRealtedWaters> getM2mListOfDaysWithRelatedMealsAlsoWithRelatedWaters();

}
```

- *obviously you'd only use the one get..... depending upon how you proceed with the relationship type*

Starting to put it all together from a Room perspective the `@Database` annotated class.

```
@Database(
        entities = {
                /* Either 1-many or many-many use the 3 core tables */
                Day.class,
                Meal.class,
                Water.class
                /* for many-many then the 2 mapping tables */
                , DayMealMap.class
                , DayWaterMap.class
        },

        version = 1,
        exportSchema = false
)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract AllDao getAllDao();

    private volatile static TheDatabase INSTANCE= null;

    public static TheDatabase getINSTANCE(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE==null) {
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase.class,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

- note `.allowMainThreadQueries` used for convenience and brevity/clarity.

Actually using all of the above to add some data and to then extract the data for both types of realtionships:-

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TheDatabase mDB;
    AllDao mDao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDB = TheDatabase.getINSTANCE(this);
        mDao = mDB.getAllDao();

        /* 1-many */
        long day001Id = mDao.insert(new Day("2022-07-08",10.10F));
        long day002Id = mDao.insert(new Day("2022-07-09",11.11F));
        long day003Id = mDao.insert(new Day("2022-07-09",12.12F));

        /* Add some related Meals (1-M) */
        long m011Id = mDao.insert(new Meal(day001Id,"09:00"));
        long m012Id = mDao.insert(new Meal(day001Id,"11:00"));
        long m013Id = mDao.insert(new Meal(day001Id,"13:00"));
        long m014Id = mDao.insert(new Meal(day001Id,"18:00"));
        long m015Id = mDao.insert(new Meal(day001Id,"21:00"));

        long m021Id = mDao.insert(new Meal(day002Id,"09:30"));
        long m022Id = mDao.insert(new Meal(day002Id,"10:15"));
        long m023Id = mDao.insert(new Meal(day002Id,"12:45"));
        long m024Id = mDao.insert(new Meal(day002Id,"17:30"));
        long m025Id = mDao.insert(new Meal(day002Id,"20:30"));

        /* Add some Waters (1-M) */
        long w011Id = mDao.insert(new Water(day001Id,100.100F));
        long w012Id = mDao.insert(new Water(day001Id,200.200F));

        long w021Id = mDao.insert(new Water(day002Id, 120.12F));
        long w022Id = mDao.insert(new Water(day002Id, 220.22F));



        /* Use the above Days, Meals and Waters to add M2M stuff */

        /* Day 1 just a subset of the 1-m's */
        mDao.insert(new DayMealMap(day001Id,m011Id));
        mDao.insert(new DayMealMap(day001Id,m013Id));
        mDao.insert(new DayMealMap(day001Id,m015Id));
        /* Day 2 just a subset of 1-m's */
        mDao.insert(new DayMealMap(day002Id, m022Id));
        mDao.insert(new DayMealMap(day002Id,m024Id));

        /* Note with 1-M day 3 was empty, this relates existing meals from day 1 and day 2 to day 3 */
        mDao.insert(new DayMealMap(day003Id,m011Id));
        mDao.insert(new DayMealMap(day003Id,m021Id));


        for (DayWithRelatedMealsAlsoWithRelatedWaters d: mDao.getListOfDaysWithRelatedMealsAndRelatedWaters()) {
            logADayWithRelatedMealsAndWaters(d,"_1-M");
        }
        for (M2MDayWithRelatedMealsAlsoWithRealtedWaters m: mDao.getM2mListOfDaysWithRelatedMealsAlsoWithRelatedWaters()) {
            logM2MDayWithRelatedMealsAndWaters(m,"_M-M");
        }

    }

    private void logADayWithRelatedMealsAndWaters(DayWithRelatedMealsAlsoWithRelatedWaters dwrmawrw, String suffix) {
        Log.d(
                "DAYINFO" + suffix,
                "Day is " + dwrmawrw.day.date +
                        " Weight is " + dwrmawrw.day.weight +
                        " ID is " + dwrmawrw.day.dayId
                + " The Day has " + dwrmawrw.mealList.size() + " meal(s) "
                + " and it has " + dwrmawrw.waterList.size() + " water(s)."
        );
        for (Meal m: dwrmawrw.mealList) {
            Log.d(
                    "DAYINFO" + suffix,
                    "\tMeal is " + m.food_meal_time + " it's parent Day has the ID " + m.dayId_Meal_Map
            );
        }
        for (Water w: dwrmawrw.waterList) {
            Log.d(
                    "DAYINFO" + suffix,
                    "\tWater is " + w.water_ml + " it's parent Day has the ID " + w.dayId_Water_Map
            );
        }
    }

    private void logM2MDayWithRelatedMealsAndWaters(M2MDayWithRelatedMealsAlsoWithRealtedWaters mdwrmawrw, String suffix) {
        Log.d(
                "DAYINFO" + suffix,
                "Day is " + mdwrmawrw.day.date +
                        " Weight is " + mdwrmawrw.day.weight +
                        " ID is " + mdwrmawrw.day.dayId
                        + " The Day has " + mdwrmawrw.mealList.size() + " meal(s) "
                        + " and it has " + mdwrmawrw.waterList.size() + " water(s)."
        );
        for (Meal m: mdwrmawrw.mealList) {
            Log.d(
                    "DAYINFO" + suffix,
                    "\tMeal is " + m.food_meal_time + " it's parent Day has the ID " + m.dayId_Meal_Map
            );
        }
        for (Water w: mdwrmawrw.waterList) {
            Log.d(
                    "DAYINFO" + suffix,
                    "\tWater is " + w.water_ml + " it's parent Day has the ID " + w.dayId_Water_Map
            );
        }
    }
}
```

- note the above is only designed to be run once as a demonstration.

**THE RESULT** (i.e. the output written to the log, with spaces added to split the two types of relationshsips):-

```
2022-07-08 12:20:01.522 D/DAYINFO_1-M: Day is 2022-07-08 Weight is 10.1 ID is 1 The Day has 5 meal(s)  and it has 2 water(s).
2022-07-08 12:20:01.522 D/DAYINFO_1-M:  Meal is 09:00 it's parent Day has the ID 1
2022-07-08 12:20:01.522 D/DAYINFO_1-M:  Meal is 11:00 it's parent Day has the ID 1
2022-07-08 12:20:01.522 D/DAYINFO_1-M:  Meal is 13:00 it's parent Day has the ID 1
2022-07-08 12:20:01.522 D/DAYINFO_1-M:  Meal is 18:00 it's parent Day has the ID 1
2022-07-08 12:20:01.522 D/DAYINFO_1-M:  Meal is 21:00 it's parent Day has the ID 1
2022-07-08 12:20:01.522 D/DAYINFO_1-M:  Water is 100.1 it's parent Day has the ID 1
2022-07-08 12:20:01.523 D/DAYINFO_1-M:  Water is 200.2 it's parent Day has the ID 1
2022-07-08 12:20:01.523 D/DAYINFO_1-M: Day is 2022-07-09 Weight is 11.11 ID is 2 The Day has 5 meal(s)  and it has 2 water(s).
2022-07-08 12:20:01.523 D/DAYINFO_1-M:  Meal is 09:30 it's parent Day has the ID 2
2022-07-08 12:20:01.523 D/DAYINFO_1-M:  Meal is 10:15 it's parent Day has the ID 2
2022-07-08 12:20:01.523 D/DAYINFO_1-M:  Meal is 12:45 it's parent Day has the ID 2
2022-07-08 12:20:01.523 D/DAYINFO_1-M:  Meal is 17:30 it's parent Day has the ID 2
2022-07-08 12:20:01.523 D/DAYINFO_1-M:  Meal is 20:30 it's parent Day has the ID 2
2022-07-08 12:20:01.523 D/DAYINFO_1-M:  Water is 120.12 it's parent Day has the ID 2
2022-07-08 12:20:01.523 D/DAYINFO_1-M:  Water is 220.22 it's parent Day has the ID 2
2022-07-08 12:20:01.523 D/DAYINFO_1-M: Day is 2022-07-09 Weight is 12.12 ID is 3 The Day has 0 meal(s)  and it has 0 water(s).



2022-07-08 12:20:01.527 D/DAYINFO_M-M: Day is 2022-07-08 Weight is 10.1 ID is 1 The Day has 3 meal(s)  and it has 0 water(s).
2022-07-08 12:20:01.527 D/DAYINFO_M-M:  Meal is 09:00 it's parent Day has the ID 1
2022-07-08 12:20:01.527 D/DAYINFO_M-M:  Meal is 13:00 it's parent Day has the ID 1
2022-07-08 12:20:01.527 D/DAYINFO_M-M:  Meal is 21:00 it's parent Day has the ID 1
2022-07-08 12:20:01.527 D/DAYINFO_M-M: Day is 2022-07-09 Weight is 11.11 ID is 2 The Day has 2 meal(s)  and it has 0 water(s).
2022-07-08 12:20:01.527 D/DAYINFO_M-M:  Meal is 10:15 it's parent Day has the ID 2
2022-07-08 12:20:01.527 D/DAYINFO_M-M:  Meal is 17:30 it's parent Day has the ID 2
2022-07-08 12:20:01.528 D/DAYINFO_M-M: Day is 2022-07-09 Weight is 12.12 ID is 3 The Day has 2 meal(s)  and it has 0 water(s).
2022-07-08 12:20:01.528 D/DAYINFO_M-M:  Meal is 09:00 it's parent Day has the ID 1
2022-07-08 12:20:01.528 D/DAYINFO_M-M:  Meal is 09:30 it's parent Day has the ID 2
```

- As can be seen, the related data is dependant upon relationship type and the data was purposefully applied to highlight the difference.

Comment: Json object has one day but that will be days so; There will be many to many relationships. because the days are plural.. actually the scenario is as follows; When a user logs into the application, a new table will appear as 01/01/2000, and then if he wants to add water, he will add water to the current day table and the water rate and percentage in the days table will increase (collection)

Comment: @He1 **BUT** a Meal/Water will only have (according to your JSON)  a SINGLE parent as such the relationships is that a **SINGLE** Day can have **MANY** Meals and also Many Waters. IF a Meal/Water could be related to many DAYS (e.g. set Meals/Water such as Roast Beef/Tonic Water) then that is where a many-many could come into play. Your JSON does not reflect the latter, but the former. Anyway will add an example in due course.

Comment: Thank you for this great example, which I will write and review the codes soon. also i don't know if this database i imagine is the right approach, I also added the uml diagram as an example. so would it be easier to do this with a nosql build?

Comment: Something came to my mind. Tables with days and ids will be created from a table named days. Also, many to many tables named water and meals will be created and when the user wants to add water, today's date will be drawn. Which id corresponds to the 01/01/2000 days table, that id will be recorded as a dayid in the water table. This will make the relational database much simpler, do you think? is it? the day table will also record the total amount of water added (can run in the background)

Comment: I want to sum the water_ml variable values ​​in arrays with day_id value of 1. These strings are mixed and there can be millions of different strings between them (I tried to emulate the Json structure because I have no SQL knowledge :))

How long do you think this interrogation and collection time might take, more than a few seconds? Please review : https://ibb.co/WBqK72M

Comment: Also, how will I do the deletion process in the code you wrote, in case of deleting any food or water, nothing will happen to the database, right?